# How to get the document response and run javascript as soon as possible in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Most Puppeteer questions focus around how to ensure the page has fully loaded and rendered. My question is the opposite:

Using Puppeteer, how can I get javascript access as soon as possible without having to wait for the `load` or `domcontentloaded` events?

When is it safe to run `page.evaluate` at the earliest opportunity, if I don't want/need to wait for the full page to render?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args) function. From the docs:

> The function is invoked after the document was created but before any of its scripts were run. This is useful to amend the JavaScript environment, e.g. to seed `Math.random`.

Be aware that you have to call `page.evaluateOnNewDocument` before `page.goto`.

Comment: Thanks but does this allow me to evaluate javascript and return a value? It seems from the docs that it's just to inject scripts.

Comment: @d-_-b Which value do you want to return? The page is blank without any DOM elements when your script is run, so what would you want to access?